# Show that the set of solutions of an inhomogeneous system $AX = B$ is either empty, or else it is an (additive) coset of $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> In the additive group $\Bbb R^m$ of vectors, let $W$ be the set of solutions of a system of homogeneous linear equations $A X = 0$. Show that the set of solutions of an inhomogeneous system $AX = B$ is either empty, or else it is an (additive) coset of $W$.

So $W$ is the set $W=\{X \in \Bbb R^m \mid AX=0 \}$ and if I define $$W' = \{X \in \Bbb R^m \mid AX=B\}$$ then the objective is to show that $W' = v + W$ for some $v \in \Bbb R^m$ or that $W' = \emptyset$?

The case $W'= \emptyset$ will be just the case when the system $AX=B$ has no solutions?

If it has, then for every $X \in W'$ we have that $AX=B$. Now since $X \in W' \subset \Bbb R^m$, then I can consider the coset $X+ W = \{X + w \mid w \in W\}$ and I have that $$A(X+w)=AX+Aw = B + 0$$ but I don't understand how I can show that $W'=v+W$ for some $v \in \Bbb R^m$?

Comment: Take two solutions $v$ and  $v'$ of $AX=B$ and consider $v'-v.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand the objective. Yes, you understand the trivial case. Thus we assume $W'$ is not empty, and so has an element, say $X' \in W'.$

The $v$ that you need can be $v=X'.$ Your work above already shows that $X'+W \subset W'.$

So what remains is to show the reverse inclusion; towards this end, pick an arbitrary $Y'\in W'$. To finish, note that the vector $Y'-X'$ belongs to $W$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is from Michael Artin - Algebra (2nd Edition), exercise 8.8.2.

We define the map $\varphi: R^m \to R^m$ that sends $X$ to $AX$, thus defining an equivalence relation that partitions $R^m$, concretely:

Obviously $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, so $W$ is the kernel of $\varphi$, (usually  denoted $\textrm{ker}\varphi$).

Let $\textrm{im}\varphi$ denote the image of $\varphi$, i.e.:

$$\textrm{im}\varphi = \{B \in R^m \mid B=\varphi(X) \textrm{ for some } X \in R^m\}$$

The inverse image (also called the fibre) of an element $B$ from $\textrm{im}\varphi$ is the subset $S$ consisting all elements $X$ such that $\varphi(X)=B$, symbolically:

$$f^{-1}(B) = \{X \in G \mid \varphi(X) = B\}$$

Note that $f^{-1}$ need not be a map.

At the same time, the fibre of $\varphi$ that contains an element $P$ of $R^m$ **is** the (additive) coset $P+W$ of $W$. (This 'is' calls for some elucidation, but suffer me to refer  those interested to 2.7 of the said (Artin's) book, especially Proposition 2.7.15. In fact these cosets partition the group $G$, and they correspond to elements of $\textrm{im}\varphi$. )

The proof follows by definition, i.e. if $\varphi$ is trivial ($A=0$), then $W=R^m$ so there is no proper coset- no other fibre than the trivial one, or equivalently, since $AX=0$ for all $X \in R^m$, no $X \in R^m$  exists such that $AX=B$ where $B$ is nonzero (i.e. the system is inhomogeneous); if $\varphi$ is not trivial, there are proper cosets, we may find certain single $P$ such that $AP=B$, and the set of solutions for $AX=B$ is the coset $P+W$, or equivalently, the fibre corresponding to $B$.

This exercise calls for merely mechanical solutions and is really a drill, so all I did is paraphrasing.